# Custom credential provider is not called on RDP - restricted admin mode

Tags: windows, rdp, credential-providers

I developed a custom credential. It's all working fine except when I'm using remote desktop with /restrictedadmin option. The login to the machine succeeds without my code interaction.

By looking at the logs, I see call to the Constructor of the class that implements `ICredentialProvider` without any call to filter or other methods.

Am I missing something? Probably I should implement function that "deals" with this situation. I'm struggling to understand how the flow goes when using in restricted mode.

I read few articles including this https://blog.ahasayen.com/restricted-admin-mode-for-rdp/ , but still I can't point on how to solve this.

Comment: Does your RDP client authenticate your credentials prior to establishing connection to remote server?

Comment: By looking on event viewer for both scenarios(RDP and RDP restricted admin) , the process prior the connection is the same.

the only diffrent that i see that probably connected to my issue that the 3rd Credential Validation(marked in blue) is missing in restricted mode.
 
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/ueVwciK.png">

My guessing is that the logon ui is skipped on restricted admin mode.